# Identifying the format of my raster layer ArcMap 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, arcgis-10.5

I have rarely worked with raster layers in ArcMap and need to follow a procedure written by a colleague who is now gone and did this 8-10 years ago and I need to know exactly what I'm working with.

In his procedure, he mentions I need to convert data (DEMs) obtained from geocomm.com into GRID format using ArcToolbox\Conversion Tools\To Raster\DEM to Raster.

The data I am using is 1/3 arc-second data from https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

This seems pretty straight forward to me. But when viewing the layer properties, I see they are already in GRID format:

[image]

Should these Rasters be converted after all or not?

Will throwing them in the conversion tool if they are already GRID mess them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following many steps assuming it was fine, the results are acceptable.

I'm assuming if ArcMAP couldn't handle the raster type for it's tools it would have given me an error and wouldn't have given me valid results, which is not the case.

Therefore, the format was indeed what it seemed and did not need additional modification.